# Loop until empty cell and add VLOOKUP

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to add a VLOOKUP function into a column and to execute it in all rows until in the data column (A1 column in this case) is a empty cell. I do not want to use a fixed range because I don't know how big it will be. Nor do I know whether the data will be in A1 column. I do not want to fix rows nor columns like A2:B100, or start on A2. All I know is that VLOOKUP will be next to the data.

Can you please help me?

Comment: I have a small example here...https://youtu.be/mCzd0G7WbvM

Answer (score 0):

last_cell=Application.Workbooks(file_name).Worksheets("SHEET").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

for i = 1 to last_cell
Application.Workbooks(file_name).Worksheets("PP_DETAILS").Range("I" & i + 1).Formula = "=your formula"
next i